# WooCommerce Custom price formula

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to create a custom formula for my woocommerce website. The site is a gold website and price of gold changes daily and there is a specific making charge for each item. What i am looking for is i can update the gold rate everyday and the price of all products is updated which will be a sum of the weight*gold rate + making charges.

Any idea how will this be achieve ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: No I have No idea how to do it ... Any Documentation link for developing stuff for Woocomerce will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Pretty good tutorial on [custom pricing for wholesale](http://w4dev.com/wp/woocommerce-custom-pricing) I believe it can largely be adapted to your situation.

Steps I would follow to do this would be:

1. Add a field to the product metabox for storing weight: not needed as you could use the built-in shipping weight
2. use the `woocommerce_get_price` filter to convert the price based on your
   formula: regular price (make price) + weight meta x whatever your
   current rate is.
3. pull price of gold from 3rd party API (I'd probably store it in a transient store so you aren't hitting the API every page load)